# Compile C to machine language and import in Python

Tags: c, pyinstaller

PyInstaller [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html?highlight=encryption#hiding-the-source-code) suggests that we can convert Python modules into C and compile the C to machine language. For the former using Cython does the task. Concerning the latter, how can we convert the C to machine language and import it into the Python source code?

Comment: Cython will take care of running the C compiler when it's building the extension.

Comment: I observe that the referenced docs are about hiding your (Python) source code.  Although compiling your module to a binary one will do that, it does introduce its own issues.  I can believe that some people do use that obfuscation technique, but I've never seen that myself.  In my experience, Cython is usually reserved for places where it provides a needed speed improvement.

Comment: @AKX True that we can import the .c and pyd into Python but from the documentation, i concluded after generating the .c and .pyd, we can take another action (making some changes to .c) before finally importing to the python. Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: @JohnBollinger What issues will occur through compiling modules to a binary one?

Comment: @Ali, off the top of my head: your compiled module will be compatible only with CPython, not other Python implementations.  With respect to CPython, it likely will have a narrower version-compatibility range than if distributed as Python.  It will support only CPython installations built with dynamic loading support (which is typical, but not universal).  You will need to compile a separate version for every machine architecture you want to support, and you cannot have end users do that, because they would need the Python source code, which you are trying to hide.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think the architecture dependence is not an issue here since OP would be using PyInstaller to ship an executable anyway.